# Ubuntu server black screen after instalation and possibly no video drivers

Tags: server, 64-bit

I got an HP proliant ml10 v2 some time ago. At first i had debian linux but i fought to switch to ubuntu server so i did that. The problem is that after instalation is complete when it boots in to the os it show a under like and something above it then it shows an underline (i think that happends.. The first caracter is litterarly cut of the screen due the server not picking up the corrct resolution and this even happends in bios). I read online that i have to boot in a special mode with the "nomodeset" prefix but i have a problem.. the grub launcher thingy dosen't seem to show up and some people suggested to use the instalation usb drive but i dont seem to find any live os on it or boot from hard drive thing.

Note: When i installed the os it prompt me at the ending of the instalation what to install and let what was selected and it plus i selected the ubuntu server base system and a file server

This is one of the problems. There is a another one that ?might happend after i get in to the os (This also happend in debian): As I said above the first caracter will be cut ( I have an 1080p monitor and i am connected via vga) BUT I saw some drivers ( http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/configu...-ubuntu-linux/ )for my server video card ( Matrox G200 ) but they they seem to be for desktop (xorg)... I am looking for some drivers for console (non-xorg).
(Ubuntu server version is Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server (64-bit) i think)

I have used Universal USB Installer to get ubuntu server on usb drive.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions and information, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Comment: What i meant is that other users have similar question posted here on ask ubuntu and they were never answered... but nvm i am ok without that sentace.

Comment: Rather than just being ok with the sentence being removed, it'd be appreciated if you add the information about your research.

Comment: Ok! I will add that soon. (I re-edited my previous comment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to get in to the console by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 . But the resolution is wrong in console. I was able to enter the server with IPMI and the resolution is 640 x and something... I have an 1080p monitor and the problem was in console (not xorg). I think i need drivers for my Matrox G200.

EDIT: I figured that i need to change the resolution via grub.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)